# Is there a word for the spot between the two eyebrows?

Tags: nouns

Is there a word for the spot between the two eyebrows (right above the nose,
but below the forehead)?

Comment: http://anatomybodygallery.com/face-anatomy/5608

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The relevant anatomical term is [***glabella,***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/glabella) defined by Oxforddictionaries.com as

> The smooth part of the forehead above and between the eyebrows.

(The plural of *glabella* is *glabellae,* though I can't think of many situations where I might have to use it.)

According to [Wikipedia,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bindi_(decoration))

> A *bindi* (Hindi: *बिंदी,* from Sanskrit *bindu*, meaning "a drop, small particle, dot") [...] is a forehead decoration worn in South Asia (particularly India, Bangladesh, Nepal, Sri Lanka and Mauritius) and Southeast Asia. Traditionally it is a bright dot of red colour applied in the centre of the forehead close to the eyebrows, but it can also consist of other colours with a sign or piece of jewelry worn at this location.
>
> Traditionally, the area between the eyebrows (where the bindi is placed) is said to be the sixth chakra, ***ajna***, the seat of "concealed wisdom".

Comment: Looks like you beat me by a few seconds.  Well played.

Comment: @AdrianW - Thanks. Such collisions of timing are more frequent here than you might expect, especially where the answer is pretty straightforward.  :)

Comment: What if it's not smooth, I.e., uni-brow. -1 to Oxford. +1 to Adrian's Wiki, calling it skin.

Comment: @Mazura - Smoothness is inherent in the word's etymology: "Early 19th century: modern Latin, from Latin *glabellus* (adjective), diminutive of *glaber* 'smooth'." You could, I suppose, use the Latin adjective *pilosus* ('hairy') as a basis for inventing a new term by analogy, *pilosa,* to mean "that part of a glabella which is covered by a unibrow". — You're welcome.  :)

Answer (score 10):

In a thousand words or less: (courtesy of Mari-Lou)

[image]

[anatomybodygallery.com](http://anatomybodygallery.com/face-anatomy/5608)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the more scientific response.  Hope this helps!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glabella

"The glabella, in humans, is the skin between the eyebrows and above the nose."

Answer (score 2):

In this video, [Pahud master class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYhduTuI_zM), the great flutist Emmanuel Pahud, explains to a student how to place flute tone in the nose rather than in the mouth.  He calls the perceived place of resonance, in the nose between the eyes, the "wasabi point", I suppose because that is where you feel the burn when eating wasabi.

Comment: Hello, Mr. Lee, +1 Thanks for the arcane info, never managed to get around to reading A.E. vanVogt, though I'm sure he/she deserved a crack. I'm familiar with Dr. Bates, though I've not tried his famous method. I'm bleeding rep here. I thought my answer was OK, once had 7 upvotes, now I'm fading fast.

Answer (score 1):

In the Old West regarding placement of a deadly bullet, the simple term "right between the eyes" was used. It is not proper nomenclature but very popular slang.  Of course glabella is the term you are looking for.